# 2 Contact Pages, need to remove one

Tags: theme, magento2.3, menu

I have a Contact Us page within the main menu in my site:

https://staging.propmasters.net/

The main menu links to https://staging.propmasters.net**/contactus.html**

Where can I edit this content? I've looked everywhere but can't find it in Pages, Widgets or Blocks

I'm using the Ultimo Theme, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's built on top of a category which I believe is called 'contact-us'. Probably because whoever built it, didn't know how to add CMS Pages to the nav. You can identify this from the body class since it contains the class `catalog-category-view`.

If it was a CMS Page you would expect to see `cms-page-view` instead of `catalog-category-view`

[image: Screenshot of identifing page type from body class]